# ¿Cómo se guardaría en Javascript el resultado de una función en una variable para almacenarlo y utilizarlo luego?

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente interrogante con este código, si invoco la función `compraTotal(referencia, impuesto, resultado);` retorna un vector de precios, los dos parámetros de entrada son vectores y funciona bien.

```
function compraTotal(dato1, dato2) {
  resultado = dato1 / dato2;
  return resultado;
}
```

Sin embargo, cuando le asigno un vector para seguir trabajando con los valores retornados `vector=compraTotal(dato1,dato2);` arroja error, así haya inicializado el `vector=[]`, por ejemplo:

```js
vector = compraTotal(dato1, dato2) {
      resultado = dato1 / dato2;
      return resultado;
    }
```

La pregunta es: ¿es incorrecto hacer eso? ¿javascript no lo admite? ¿debería es realizar otro proceso similar y descartar este? La idea es guardar el resultado de la función en una variable... ¿debería entonces ser con `let vector = compraTotal(dato1, dato2)`?

Comment: 1. Cuales son los datos que estas pasando como parámetro? 2. Qué error te da?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo diria que es incorrecto, por que por consola me da error sin embargo de esta manera si me funciona(Deberias indicarnos que parametros estas pasando a la funcion):

```js
let dato1 = 12;
let dato2 = 2;

function compraTotal(dato1, dato2) {
  resultado = dato1 / dato2;
  return resultado;
}

let vector = compraTotal(dato1, dato2);
console.log(vector);
```

Comment: si no conoces que parámetros esta pasando no puedes dar una respuesta, obviamente aquí funciona por que pasas números, pero que tal si el OP esta pasando objetos, arrays u otro dato? Sin los detalles suficiente en la pregunta tu respuesta es incorrecta.

Comment: Segun el titulo de la pregunta, respondi a la pregunta, no me parece que sea incorrecta

Comment: Esto no resuelve el problema del OP por que en primer lugar no sabemos cual es el error, en tu respuesta das solución a un error que no sabes si existe (incluso según el planteamiento de tu respuesta en la pregunta original no habría error)

Comment: El indica que la funcion es correcta y no tiene problema, lo que el quiere es saber como usar el resultado de la funcion afuera de esta. Por parametros no habria que preocuparnos, el mismo cita "La idea es guardar el resultado de la función en una variable..." a lo cual mi respuesta se adaptaria.